# Could not load file or assembly 'X' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: dll, dependencies, unmanaged

Shot in the dark but I thought I'd try to post in hopes of some genius out there...

**Background:**
I am trying to added automated unit testing to a huge unmanaged C++ project.  For various reasons within our group, we want to use MSTest.  As a result, classes and functions from an unmanged MFC C++ project need to be called from a managed C# project.

**Proof of Feasability:**
I have accomplished this on a small scale to prove that it does, in fact, work.  This is what I did:

1. Create an unmanaged MFC C++ project (SOURCE) with few classes and functions; compile as a static library (.lib)
2. Create a managed C++ project (WRAPPER) that links to the aforementioned static library.  Each wrapper class simply creates a pointer to an object of the corresponding class in the SOURCE and calls each of its functions, just like one would expect a wrapper class to do.  Compile as a dynamic library (.dll).
3. Create a C# project (C_SHARP).  Add a reference to the WRAPPER dll.  Now you can call the WRAPPER function directly (which, in turn, call the unmanaged SOURCE functions).

This works.  I can share the example project if you want to see it.  The next step was taking the concept and getting to work with our gigantic, highly coupled codebase.

**Where I'm at now:**
Long story short, I have the WRAPPER project building successfully and creating a DLL.  I add a reference to my C_SHARP project.  I try to run it but it stops immediately with the message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occured in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Coule not load file or assembly 'WRAPPER.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Ran dependency walker in profile mode and got this:

> > ---
> >
> > Starting profile on 3/6/2012 at 10:45:11 AM
> >
> > **Operating System:** Microsoft Windows XP Professional (32-bit), version 5.01.2600 Service Pack 3
> >     **Program Executable:** c:\example\testing\bin\debug\TESTING.EXE
> >
> > **Program Arguments:**
> >
> > **Starting Directory:** C:\example\Testing\bin\Debug\
> >
> > **Search Path:** C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
> >
> > **Options Selected:**
> >     Simulate ShellExecute by inserting any App Paths directories into the PATH environment variable.
> >
> > Log DllMain calls for process attach and process detach messages.
> >
> > Hook the process to gather more detailed dependency information.
> >
> > Log LoadLibrary function calls.
> >
> > Log GetProcAddress function calls.
> >
> > Log first chance exceptions.
> >
> > Log debug output messages.
> >
> > Use full paths when logging file names.
> >
> > Log a time stamp with each line of log.
> >
> > Automatically open and profile child processes.
> >
> > 00:00:00.000: Started "c:\example\testing\bin\debug\TESTING.EXE" (process 0xF4) at address 0x00400000.  Successfully hooked module.
> >
> > 00:00:00.047: Loaded "c:\windows\system32\NTDLL.DLL" at address 0x7C900000.  Successfully hooked module.
> >
> > 00:00:00.140: Loaded "c:\windows\system32\MSCOREE.DLL" at address 0x79000000.  Successfully hooked module.
> >     00:00:00.250: Loaded "c:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL" at address 0x7C800000.  Successfully hooked module.
> >
> > 00:00:00.250: DllMain(0x7C900000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\system32\NTDLL.DLL" called.
> >
> > 00:00:00.250: DllMain(0x7C900000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\system32\NTDLL.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
> >
> > 00:00:00.297: DllMain(0x7C800000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL" called.
> >
> > 00:00:00.312: DllMain(0x7C800000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
> >
> > 00:00:00.312: Injected "c:\documents and settings\administrator\desktop\depends22_x86\DEPENDS.DLL" at address
> >     0x08370000.
> >
> > 00:00:00.344: DllMain(0x79000000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\windows\system32\MSCOREE.DLL" called.
> >
> > 00:00:00.344: DllMain(0x08370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\documents and
> >     settings\administrator\desktop\depends22_x86\DEPENDS.DLL" called.
> >
> > 00:00:00.344: DllMain(0x08370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\documents and
> >     settings\administrator\desktop\depends22_x86\DEPENDS.DLL" returned 1
> >     (0x1).
> >
> > 00:00:00.344: GetProcAddress(0x7C800000 [c:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsAlloc") called from
> >     "c:\windows\system32\MSCOREE.DLL" at address 0x79006F3C and returned
> >     0xFFBADD11.
> >
> > 00:00:00.359: Exited "c:\example\testing\bin\debug\TESTING.EXE" (process 0xF4) with code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).

**Problem:**
What is happening?  Why does this work in my small feasibility example but not with the actual code I want?  I am linking the WRAPPER project to several other libraries but why would that matter?